# "The upgrade policy is not allowed" ClusterConfigurationUpgrade fails on Standalone Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

v5.6.220.9494

I've been digging the last few hours trying to figure this out. I'm receiving the following error when attempting a clusterconfigurationupgrade:

```
System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.ClusterManifestValidationException: Cluster manifest validation failed with exception System.ArgumentException: The upgrade policy is not allowed
at System.Fabric.Management.WindowsFabricValidator.FabricSettingsValidator.CompareSettings(ClusterManifestType newClusterManifest, String nodeTypeNameFilter)
at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.CompareAndAnalyze(ClusterManifestType currentClusterManifest, ClusterManifestType targetClusterManifest, Infrastructure infrastructure, DeploymentParameters parameters)
at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.FabricValidatorWrapper.CompareAndAnalyze(ClusterManifestType currentClusterManifest, ClusterManifestType targetClusterManifest, Infrastructure infrastructure, DeploymentParameters parameters)
at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperationPrivate(DeploymentParameters parameters)
at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.DeploymentOperation.ExecuteOperation(DeploymentParameters parameters)
at System.Fabric.FabricDeployer.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I ended up having to rollback the upgrade to recover two nodes. If anyone could help point me in the right direction on resolving this error it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you're trying to accomplish. There are upgrade policies for the cluster and the virtual machine scale set. What have you changed? How did you change it? A policy value is not correct, but I have no idea which one.

Comment: Thanks for replying Dan.  This is an on prem standalone instance of SF.  The only thing I was trying to accomplish was adding capacity metrics to the cluster config and update the SF cluster with that new config.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this error?